# Php - How to create a GEOJSON File with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, geojson

I am wanting to build a Linestring function from Php to convert it to GeoJson. The function is the following:

```
var linea = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
     { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0]]
          },
        "properties": {
          "name": "enlace"
                }
        }
   
       ]
     }
```

The code is the following:

```
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature', 
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'LineString',
            'coordinates' => array($row['lon'], $row['lat'])
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'name' => $row['equipo'],
            )
        );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

}

$variable="var geonokia= " .json_encode($geojson); 
file_put_contents('D:\equipo.js',$variable);
```

**How do I create an array of 2 latitudes and 2 longitudes to create the line?**

"'coordinates' => array($row['lon'], $row['lat'])"

**for create an**

"coordinates": [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0]]  ----->>> **2 POINTS**

Comment: Will this routine only ever extract 1 feature, so all of the rows are related to the one set of coordinates?

Comment: I have in a table $latA, $lonA , $LatB, $LonB , and i need:  "coordinates": [[$latA, $lonA], [$latB, $lonB]]

Comment: `'coordinates' => [ [ $row['latA'], $row['lonA'] ], [ $row['latB'], $row['lonB'] ] ]` …?

Comment: No, have an error

Comment: Quote error messages verbatim, instead of just telling us that you _have_ errors …

Comment: Ok, but there is not much information about the error, look:   "There is a Syntax error on line 250. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error"